# Python - Split a string but keep contiguous uppercase letters

Tags: python, string, split

I would like to split strings to separate words by capital letters, but if it contains contiguous uppercase letters, split it to one word until before the final letter (that probably starts a new word..)

For example:

```
splitThreeWords -> [split, three, words]
SplitThreeWords -> [split, three, words]
ILOSummit -> [ILO, summit]
```

Comment: How would you know the `s` belongs to summit?

Comment: I'll not know for sure but assume that's the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) with a capturing group (to keep the splitter pattern) and filter out the empty chunks:

```
import re


def split_by_title_word(s):
    return [chunk for chunk in re.split(r"([A-Z][a-z]+)", s) if chunk]


print(split_by_title_word("splitThreeWords"))
print(split_by_title_word("SplitThreeWords"))
print(split_by_title_word("IOLSummit"))
```

**Output**

```
['split', 'Three', 'Words']
['Split', 'Three', 'Words']
['IOL', 'Summit']
```

The pattern `[A-Z][a-z]+` represents a [title](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.istitle) word.